# How do i display data from db on a route change?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

I'm working on a messenger-like app in vue.js + firebase. What im'trying to do is to - on every route change get some of the data coresponding to the id(stored in route) from db and then display it on the screen. I am getting some weird behaviour with this data and it doesn't work how intended.

The code:

```
  methods: {
    getRoomName() {
      db.collection("rooms")
        .doc(this.params)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => (this.roomName = snapshot.data().name));
    },
  },
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      this.getRoomName();
    },
  },
```

where data:

```
data() {
    return {
      input: "",
      roomName: "",
      params: this.$route.params.id,
      message: "",
      roomNameTest: "",
    };
  },
```

template: `<span class="roomName">{{roomName}}</span>`

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly "weird behaviour" means? First thing I noticed is that you are calling this.$route at data(), it will not work. If you need to populate something, try using Vue https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: it started to work as intended as soon as i removed this.$route in data and moved it directyl to the function. Thanks!

Comment: I will elaborate an answer, please accept it to help others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I noticed is that you are calling this.$route at data(), it will not work. If you need to populate something, try using [Vue Lifecycle Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

Answer (score 0):

The life cycle hooks (mounted/created are for these kinds of things. They are called when the vue instance is created and mounted respectively.

```js
mounted() // it can also work for the created hook {
  this.getRoomName();
},
```

The watcher watches for route change but is not really suited for this situation because by the time the route changes, the component in which it's watching has not been instantiated. The mounted/created hooks are triggered when that particular Vue instance you are watching in is instantiated/mounted respectively.

An appropriate time to use a watcher for a route change is if the params on a url changes and you need to do something. An example is changing `/users/1 to` /users/2`. This will work because the same component is used and the watcher will detect the change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my case im changing routes from rooms/{id_of_the_room} to the rooms/{id_of_another_room} so i think it's fine in this case. Really appreciate some information about the life cycle hooks

Comment: Do the id's use the same component?

Comment: yup
```
{
    path: '/rooms/:id',
    name: 'Pokoje',
    component: Home,
  },
```

Comment: That's ok, then. It should work. You said it works when the $route object is put in the function. What exactly do you want to happen. As an aside, watchers don't work when a component is first created (this occurs when the component is routed to or the browser refreshed). In those cases, you will need a `created` or `mounted` hook. That may explain it. The watcher works subsequently (in this case when navigating from params to params within the same component. You can read more about vue lifecycle hooks [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-component-lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `$route.path` to watch for changes to get the new IDs.

Component

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState('products', ['products']),
  },
  watch: {
    '$route.path'() {
      this.bindProducts(this.IdFromUrl)
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.bindProducts(this.IdFromUrl)
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions('products', ['bindProducts']),
  }
```

And the running in my store there is vuexfire working.
Alternatively you could bind your own data.